# Tailwind not applying styles in subpages Next13

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

Today I've begun using NextJS, I want to use tailwind alongside it following [this](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/tailwind-css) article from the NextJS documentation.

When I try to the main / directory Tailwind is working perfectly, the issue comes whenever I try to go into any of the directories that are under the page folder Tailwind does not work (Default styles, classes having no impact).

**Folder Structure (Basic)**

```
my-app/
├─ app/
│  ├─ globals.css
│  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
├─ pages/
│  ├─ listings/
│  │  ├─ talent.tsx
├─ tailwind.config.js
```

**Tailwind config**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: I've now tried a few different thing but importing the globals.css into each file seems to work, feel a little clunky though and I assumed that's the reason globals.css was imported into layout

Answer (score 3):

In the article you provided, they are importing the `gloabls.css` file in their `layout.tsx` component, which is then used by all the pages in the app. If you aren't using the layout file in the same manner, you will need to import the CSS file on the pages where you want the styles to apply.

I suggest you either make use of the layout component in your `page.tsx` file to easily share the styles among your entire app, or use the per-page layout method that NextJS explains [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

worked for me.